# Не работает import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

Все привет, учу hibernate, столкнулась с проблемой, что Java не видит

```
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
```

Хотя hibernate к проекту подключен и другие импорты такие, как

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
```

видны и работают. Как решить? В мавене есть зависимости

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.21.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.21.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

для решения моей проблемы, необходимо было поменять версию зависимости

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```